# SendGrid does not send an email (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, email, ecmascript-6, sendgrid

I have this `Mailer.js` file

```
   const sendgrid = require('sendgrid');
    const helper = sendgrid.mail;
    const keys = require('../config/keys');

    class Mailer extends helper.Mail {
        constructor({ subject, recipients }, content) {
            super();

            this.sgApi = sendgrid(keys.sendGridKey);
            this.from_email = new helper.Email('no-reply@emaily.com');
            this.subject = subject;
            this.body = new helper.Content('text/html', content);
            this.recipients = this.formatAddresses(recipients);

            this.addContent(this.body);
            this.addClickTracking();
            this.addRecipients();
        }

        formatAddresses(recipients) {
            return recipients.map(({ email }) => {
                return new helper.Email(email);
            });
        }

        addClickTracking() {
            const trackingSettings = new helper.TrackingSettings();
            const clickTracking = new helper.ClickTracking(true, true);

            trackingSettings.setClickTracking(clickTracking);
            th

is.addTrackingSettings(trackingSettings);
    }

    addRecipients() {
        const personalize = new helper.Personalization();

        this.recipients.forEach(recipient => {
            personalize.addTo(recipient);
        });
        this.addPersonalization(personalize);
    }

    async send() {
        const request = this.sgApi.emptyRequest({
            method: 'POST',
            path: '/v3/mail/send',
            body: this.toJSON()
        });

        const response = await this.sgApi.API(request);
        return response;
    }
}

module.exports = Mailer;
```

And also, I have `surveyRoutes.js` file, which container information about route

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const requireLogin = require('../middlewares/requireLogin');
const requireCredits = require('../middlewares/requireCredits');
const Mailer = require('../services/Mailer');
const surveyTemplate = require('../services/emailTemplates/surveyTemplate');

const Survey = mongoose.model('surveys');

    module.exports = app => {
        app.post('/api/surveys', requireLogin, requireCredits, async (req, res) => {
            const {title, subject, body, recipients} = req.body;

            const survey = new Survey({
                title,
                subject,
                body,
                recipients: recipients.split(',').map(email => ({ email: email.trim() })),
                _user: req.user.id,
                dateSent: Date.now()
            });

            const mailer = new Mailer(survey, surveyTemplate(survey));
            try {
               await mailer.send();
            }
            catch(e){
                console.log(e);
            }
            });
    };
```

And, inside the main file, I use this scructure to use surveyRoutes

```
require('./routes/surveyRoutes')(app);
```

So, when I am trying to send email, diong it with `axios.post`, no errors, and it seems to be okey, but email is not delivered.

If you see any problems with the code, please, let me know.

Comment: May be it is problem with the send grid. I have also faced the same issue while sending email from sendgrip.

Comment: @sohamdodia what do you mean, "problem with the send grid"? Please, explain.

Comment: May be you have exceed the limit in send grid or you are sending so many mails from send grid and all the mail goes into spam. So you are not allowed to send the mails.

Answer (score 0):

A purely anecdotal point, however the following explanation seems to have prevented a number of people from successfully sending emails from their Express Server to the SendGrid API.

Many people report, after having signed up for the free tier of the SendGrid service, that since they did not enter a verifiable Company Name and Company Website address into their account settings, SendGrid would not approve free tier access and it manifested in their applications inability to process an email through SendGrid.  One person actually claimed to have verified this scenario directly with SendGrid Support.

On an aside, I'm assuming that your SendGrid API key was copied accurately to the key store on your Express Server.

Answer (score 0):

Long shot but for anyone experiencing this, check the API key access in the SendGrid dashboard. Mine was restricted and for some reason only allowed emails to be sent from localhost. Enabling 'full access' got it working on my production site.